# Syntax/Functions used in the OpenCL-Implemantation of OpenCV

Tags: opencv, opencl

I try to understand the use of OpenCL within OpenCV but I don´t get it:

This is an example Codepart from `orb.cpp` where a Kernel with the name `ORB_HarrisResponses` located in `orb.cl` is created (propably):

```
ocl::Kernel hr_ker("ORB_HarrisResponses", ocl::features2d::orb_oclsrc,
            format("-D ORB_RESPONSES -D blockSize=%d -D scale_sq_sq=%.12ef -
            D HARRIS_K=%.12ff", blockSize, scale_sq_sq, harris_k));
return hr_ker.args(ocl::KernelArg::ReadOnlyNoSize(imgbuf),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrReadOnly(layerinfo),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrReadOnly(keypoints),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrWriteOnly(responses),
            nkeypoints).run(1, globalSize, 0, true);
```

But this isn't the regular OpenCL-Syntax (functions like clCreateKernel ...). Does someone know where I can get a basic understanding of the OpenCV`s OpenCL implementations to answer questions like:

- Where is the connection between the "normal" OpenCL and the OpenCV OpenCL?
- Where the program is built from the kernel source files？
- Where is the function, which creates the kernel explained？
- etc

I couldn´t find a document or related questions on the web.
Thanks

**Edit: Thanks for answering it helped to understand a few things:**

```
 ocl::Kernel hr_ker("ORB_HarrisResponses", ocl::features2d::orb_oclsrc,
            format("-D ORB_RESPONSES -D blockSize=%d -D scale_sq_sq=%.12ef -D HARRIS_K=%.12ff", blockSize, scale_sq_sq, harris_k));
```

In this part the kernel code `ORB_HarrisResponses` located in `orb.cl` build within the string `ocl::features2d::orb_oclsrc` is created as `hr_ker` (right?).

- But what does the format(...) thing do?

if `hr_ker.empty()` return false;

```
return hr_ker.args(ocl::KernelArg::ReadOnlyNoSize(imgbuf),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrReadOnly(layerinfo),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrReadOnly(keypoints),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrWriteOnly(responses), 
            nkeypoints).run(1, globalSize, 0, true);
```

In this part of the Kernel arguments `imgbuf`, `layerinfo`, `keypoints` are set and output of the kernel is stored in responses.

- What is going on with nkeypoints?
- Why no `ocl::KernelArg` infront of this parameter?
- The kernel in `orb.cl` has 7 arguments but only 5 are set, why?
- What exactly is returned from return `hr_ker.args(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is kind of internal OpenCV "sugar" to not repeat some common code blocks. Unfortunately there is no good documentation so the only way to learn it is looking through source code and examples.

Some tips for you:

- Connection between OpenCL API and opencv are in `modules\core\src\ocl.cpp` (see `Kernel`, `Kernel::Impl`, `Program`, `ProgramSource`, `KernelArg` classes).
- Source code of kernels stored in *.cl files (for example ORB kernels are in modules\features2d\src\opencl\orb.cl file). On module building code of kernels are copying to auto-generated cpp file (for example opencl_kernels_features2d.cpp) and code can be accessed by `ocl::features2d::orb_oclsrc`.
- To use opencl implementation in opencv you need to pass to function `cv::UMat` instead of regular `cv::Mat` (see `CV_OCL_RUN_` macro and `cv::OutputArray::isUMat()` method).

Basically all opencl implementation inside opencv does the following:

- Defines kernel parameters, like global size, block size,  etc.
- Creates cv::ocl::Kernel using string with source code and defined parameters. (If kernel is not created or there is no opencl implementation for specified input parameters processing is passed to regular cpu code).
- Pass kernel arguments via `cv::ocl::KernelArgs`. There is several types of parameters to optimize processing: read-only, write-only, constant, etc.
- Run kernel.

So for end user using opencl implementation is *transparent*. If something goes wrong processing is switched to cpu implementation.

Let's discuss following code snippet:

```
  return hr_ker.args(ocl::KernelArg::ReadOnlyNoSize(imgbuf),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrReadOnly(layerinfo),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrReadOnly(keypoints),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrWriteOnly(responses),
            nkeypoints).run(1, globalSize, 0, true);
```

and ocl function declaration:

```
ORB_HarrisResponses(__global const uchar* imgbuf, int imgstep, int imgoffset0,
                    __global const int* layerinfo, __global const int* keypoints,
                    __global float* responses, int nkeypoints )
```

- `nkeypoints` is integer, so no need to wrap it to `ocl::KernelArg`. It will be passed directly to kernel.
- `ocl::KernelArg::ReadOnlyNoSize` actually expands to three parameters: imgbuf, imgstep, imgoffset0.
- Other kernel arguments doesn't expand, so it represent single parameter.
- `hr_ker.args` returns reference to `cv::ocl::Kernel` so you may use following construction: `kernel.args(...).run(...)`.

Some useful links:

- `cv::format` [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/da1/classcv_1_1Formatter.html). It works like [`boost::format`](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.format).

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question :). Maybe you can look at the edited question again :)

Comment: Hi again, i have a question related to your answer, so I hope you will look here again :) You said: "ocl::KernelArg::ReadOnlyNoSize actually expands to three parameters: imgbuf, imgstep, imgoffset0." how do i get the values from imgstep and imgoffset? Thanks :)

Comment: @akarsakov actually in opencv3.3.0, cv::ocl::KernelArg::ReadWrite() will expand to five argument with something like `__global uchar* dst, int dst_step, int dst_offset, int dst_rows, int dst_cols`